# Swift - Expand ViewController behind the TabBar

Tags: swift

I created three `tabItems` in `UITabBarViewController` which is pushed to another UINavigationController. One of the three tabItems is a `UINavigationController`, the other two are `UIViewController`. In order to make sure there is only one navigation bar is shown when it is in non-root viewController of the tabItem which is a UINavigationController, the parent UINavigationBar will be hidden.

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        if let navigationC = self.navigationController, navigationC.viewControllers.count == 1 {
            self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: false)
            self.parent?.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: false)
        } else {
            self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(false, animated: false)
            self.parent?.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: false)
        }
        self.setupViewConstraints()
    }
```

The issue here is, if I navigate to the 2nd `UIViewController` of the `UINavigationController`, then switch from `UINavigationController` to `UIViewController` and back to the `UINavigationController`, the bottom of the `UINavigationController` is moved up which should equal to the bottom of the `UIScreen`. If I navigate back to the root view of the `UINavigationController`, the bottom of the `UINavigationcontroller` is equal to the `UIScreen` which is correct.

How can I make sure all `UIViewControllers'` bottom in the navigationController is equal to `UIScreen`? It may due to there are two navigationBar in the non-root viewController of UINavigationController tabItem.

Below is the code I used to create `UITabBarViewController`:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    tabBar.tintColor = UIColor.fromHexString("0078d7")
    tabBar.barTintColor = UIColor.white

    let firstViewController = FirstViewController()
    firstViewController.delegate = self
    firstViewController.tabBarItem = UITabBarItem.init(title: "first", image: , tag: 0)


    let secondViewController = SecondViewController()
    secondViewController.delegate = self
    secondViewController.tabBarItem = UITabBarItem.init(title: "second", image: , tag: 1)

    let thirdViewController = ThirdViewController()
    thirdViewController.delegate = self
    thirdViewController.tabBarItem = UITabBarItem.init(title: "third", image: , tag: 3)

    let initialNavigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: firstViewController)
    initialNavigationController.navigationItem.title =  ""
    self.addChildViewController(initialNavigationController)
    self.addChildViewController(secondViewController)
    self.addChildViewController(thirdViewController)

    self.navigateToLastVisitedViewController(navigationController: initialNavigationController)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In above `viewDidLoad` method of `UITabBarViewController` just make your `tabBar` `translucent`. This will allow you content `viewController` to lay beneath `UITabBar` object.

## Swift

```
self.tabBar.isTranslucent = true
```

---

## Objective-C

```
[self.tabBar setTranslucent:YES];
```

> Same logic will be use in `UINavigationBar` case.

Comment: The UIViewController bottom is still equal to the top of tab bar if the UIViewController isn't the root one of UINavigationController.